# Google Drive API get revisions

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to get a file (non google format - Excel file) through the google API by calling a GET requests against the API by passing the file Id and the revision Id.

In the response, I see the selfURL and downloadURL both of which are not working.

I'm getting an error (it needs authentication when trying to download - I am using free account, not paid one) and if I paste in the browser, it's not getting anything.

Any idea how I can download the file?

Comment: Have you resolved this? I provided you a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get your xlsx (Excel) revision file:

Step 1. You have to know which *revisionId*, you want to download. You can check list of revision ids by entering fileId in the [revision: list 'Try it'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list#try-it). Authorize and Execute.

Step 2.  Go to [revisions: get Try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get#try-it)
     [image]

If the response is 200, OK,check the reponse body. Use the exportLink ending in `&exportFormat=xlsx` for xlsx:

```
 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet:
```

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={FILE_ID}&revision=6&exportFormat=xlsx`

Click that and it will download the file.Hope it helps.